# CSS - Center Header background Image in a auto sizing container with auto side resizing

Tags: html, css

My css container currently has a static width of 900px and there is a header background image of the same width. I would like to make the container autosize and have solid color auto sizing areas on either end of the centered header background image.

Thanks!

zucchini

this is what I have been working with

```
/* ------------------------------
global styles
------------------------------ */

body
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
color: #F0F0F0;
background: #FFFFFF;
}

a:link { color: #B52c07; }
a:visited { color: #b93411; }
a:focus { color: #000; }
a:hover { color: #7d8206; }
a:active { color: red; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin: 0 0 .5em; }

h2
{
color: #000000;
font: 140% Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

h2 a { text-decoration: none; }

h3
{
color: #000000;
font: 110%  Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

/* ------------------------------
container styles
------------------------------ */

#container
{
margin: 1em auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

/* ------------------------------
header styles
------------------------------ */

#headertop
{
position:relative;
height: 178px;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
/*background-position:center;
/*position:static;*/
background-image:url(../images/Header.jpg);
/*background-position:center;
/*background: url(../images/Header.jpg);*/
background-color:#000000;
border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code/live example?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add an autowidth container - just use the `body` element for your background image (as it will span across the entire screen, regardless of the size of your containers.

Answer (score -1):

Set your header background color to solid color you want and then center the background image with no-repeat.

Here is what you should do:

```
#headertop
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/900x100/ab24ab/0011ff.png&text=Header);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: That does not create the desired effect.